Testing Workflow In AutoGen Studio
I'm very new to this stuff and have been trying to figure this out for awhile.
When I got to test my autogen studio 2.0 workflows I receive this error message:
Error occurred while processing message: 
api_key is not present in llm_config or OPENAI_API_KEY env variable for agent ** Code_and_AI_Tutor**. 
Update your workflow to provide an api_key to use the LLM.

I went to the workflow manager and added the necessary information, but I'm not sure if that's where I should add it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
